# Brush in sculpt mode rotate

Tags: sculpt-mode, brushes

the brush began to spin according to the shape of the figure.
How to solve this problem?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you want it to stop adjusting to the normal of your mesh or is it that the adjustments are coming out strangely. If so perhaps you need to recalculate the normals of your object.

Comment: I want it to stop adjusting to the normal of my mesh. Is it possible?

Comment: Couldn't figure out a way to do that unfortunately...